# OrderBy nested property

Tags: c#, linq, lambda

I'm trying to use OrderBy for a nested property but I can't get it to work.

Models:

```
public class TPRenewalCycle
{
    public virtual ICollection<TPCaseEvent> CaseEvents { get; set; }
}

public class TPCaseEvent
{
    public DateTime? DueDate { get; set; }
}
```

Method:

```
List<TPRenewalCycle> cycles = renewalCycles

var nextRenewalCycle = cycles.OrderBy(cycle => cycle.CaseEvents.OrderBy(caseEvent => caseEvent.DueDate)).FirstOrDefault();
```

This gives me the runtime error:

> At least one object must implement IComparable.

Is this due to the `nullable DateTime` or `CaseEvents`? How can I solve this?

In T-SQL I can do this:

```
SELECT CE.DueDate
  FROM TPRenewalCycles RC
  INNER JOIN TPCaseEvents CE on (CE.BusinessSystemId = RC.BusinessSystemId and CE.CaseId = RC.CaseId and CE.Action = RC.Action and CE.Cycle = RC.Cycle)
  Order by CE.DueDate
```

Comment: @SamvelPetrosov No it shouldn't

Comment: Is this Entity Framework?

Comment: You can just translate your tsql query almost as is to LINQ query.

Comment: `cycles.OrderBy(cycle => cycle.CaseEvents.OrderBy(...))` means you try to Order by the results of the inner OrderBy, an `IEnumerable<>`. Like 'sort  classes by their list of students lastname'.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Since `OrderBy` expression needs to supply a value to be used as the comparison key for the entire record, you need to select the earliest due date in the list:

```
var nextRenewalCycle = cycles
    .OrderBy(cycle => cycle.CaseEvents.Select(caseEvent => caseEvent.DueDate).Min())
    .FirstOrDefault();
```

If you are looking for the earliest date, as in your SQL query, you could use `SelectMany` instead:

```
var nextRenewalCycle = cycles
    .SelectMany(cycle => cycle.CaseEvents)
    .Select(caseEvent => caseEvent.DueDate)
    .Min();
```